# Using a function to output HTML in PHP

Tags: php, function

I am trying to get a function to work and output the styles for variable but am unable to get them to work.

```
function frontstyle(){
  $worldstyle = $data[\"worldpercent\"] < \"75\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
  $USA        = $data[\"USApercent\"] <= \"22\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
}
```

Then in my code down a bit i have

```
foreach ($result as $data) {
  if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'frontpage') !== false) {
    frontstyle();
  }
```

I have also tried the funtion after the foreach but results in no data showing at all.  My goal is to have a funtion that is inserted in the if statement and if frontpage then display that inline css.

My inline css block

```
<td width="75px" $USA><b>$ {$data["USApercent"]}</td>
```

This works if i add the variables directly within the if statement like this

```
foreach ($result as $data) {
  if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'frontpage') !== false) {

          $worldstyle = $data[\"worldpercent\"] < \"75\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
          $USA  = $data[\"USApercent\"] <= \"22\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
 }

  echo <<<EOD
  <tr >
    <td width="120px" id="USA"><b>{$data["USApercent"]}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't *work* because `$worldstyle` and `$USA` defined inside function `frontstyle()` are local to the function scope, and similarly, you are not feeding `frontstyle()` with `$data`, so it's `undefined`.

I.e. you need a way of *returning* values from the function to allow your `if` loop to work with the values, and at the same time feed `$data` to the function on each iteration of your `foreach` loop.

There are different ways you could envisage doing this, but one would be to return an array with both `$worldstyle` and `$USA`. You can then reference these values inside the array for your styling needs.

I.e. change your function to:

```
function frontstyle($data = [], $worldstyle = "", $USA = "", $frontstyle = [])
{
    $worldstyle = $data["worldpercent"] < 75 ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
    $USA = $data["USApercent"] <= 22 ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
    $frontstyle = ['world' => $worldstyle, 'usa' => $USA];
    return $frontstyle; // return the array with styling
}
```

*side note: don't use all caps for variable names(e.g. USA) unless they are constants*

Then inside your `if` loop you can do:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'frontpage') !== false) {
    $frontstyle = frontstyle(); // you now have access to the styling values
    $worldstyle = $frontstyle['world'];
    $USA = $frontstyle['usa'];
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me.  Thank you so much for the help and understanding